# Open in new tab from :Lexplore

Tags: vim, keymapping

I've got .vimrc set up so I can open and close Lexplore easily with fe like this:

```
map fe :Lexplore<CR>
```

My question is: Can I make it so that files opened from the Lexplore window will open in a new tab in the right side window? (buffers?)

Update:
This is the effect I am looking for. I want files opened from Lexp to open up in a new tab on the right hand side.
[image: screenshot of the VIM editor]

Comment: There is `t` to open in a new tab. But when a file is opened in a new tab, there is only one window. Would you like the file opened in a new tab *then* open `:Lex` again ? Note that netrw buffers are different from tabs to tabs and can thus can view different directories.

Comment: Possibly a confusion between tab and split or window: do you want to open the file in a new window on the right or a new tab? Check :help tabpages and :help windows for the differences

Comment: I added an image to try and explain what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but hopefully this helps someone else. To open a selected file in a new vertical split as indicated in Brian's image, press `v`.

Other commands in this view (netrw) for opening the selected file include:

- `o` - open in new horizontal split
- `t` - open in new tab instead of a split
- `p` - preview

You can view the full list of these commands with `:help netrw-quickmap`